# changing /etc/pam.d location

Tags: pam, testing

is there a way to change location of */etc/pam.d* directory, or is it hardcoded into PAM?
can't it be changed with some environment variable for specific client programs?

for example:

> PAM_CONFIG_ROOT=/tmp/pam_test_configs pam_client_app

or it can't be done for some reason I don't see now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pam(8)` manual page says explicitly that it considers `/etc/pam.conf` but only if `/etc/pam.d/` doesn't exist. No mention whatsoever of alternative places. The definite guide is [here](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/).

Either arrange for your modules to be called only by you, or use a virtual machine set up for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the Linux PAM sources. */etc/pam.conf*, */etc/pam.d* are hardcoded there. :(